# how to have a class and superclass in two files (Typescript)

Tags: class, module, typescript, require

How do I split a class + subclass across two files in TypeScript?

```
// MongoModel.js
class MongoModel {
   ...
}
export = MongoModel;
```

then in another file:

```
import MongoModel = require("./MongoModel");
```

but this is giving error `File ....MongoModel.ts is not a module`

Do i need to use some module syntax to bundle them together, like a Java package?

Comment: are you using the `es6` target in your compiler options? If so, you must export like this: `export class MongoModel { ... }` and remove the `export=MongoModel`. You would import it like this: `import {MongoModel} from './MongoModel'`

Comment: Or you can use: `export default class MongoModel {...}` and import it: `import MongoModel from './MongoModel'`. Like this you can rename the class at import time, e.g. `import BaseMongoModel from './MongoModel'`

Comment: these look helpful. add answers so i can accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you used for exporting and importing modules work when you target `es5` in your compiler configuration.

When targeting `es6`, you have the following ways of exporting/importing modules:

```
// in MongoClass.ts
export class MongoClass {
    // ... code here
}

// and in other file
import {MongoClass} from '/path/to/MongoClass';
```

or you can use `default export`;

```
// in MongoClass.ts
export default class MongoClass { ... }
export const somethingElse = 5;

// and import in some other file
// note that MongoClass can be renamed when is exported as default exported member
import BaseMongo from '/path/to/MongoClass';

// this cannot be renamed when importing
import {somethingElse} from '/path/to/MongoClass';
```